# How do I deactivate an egg?

Tags: python, uninstallation, egg

I've installed cx_Oracle (repeatedly) and I just can't get it to work on my Intel Mac. How do I deactivate/uninstall it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply delete the `.egg` file

On OS X they are installed into `/Library/Python/2.5/site-packages/` - in that folder you should find a file named `cx_Oracle.egg` or similar. You can simple delete this file and it will be gone.

One way of finding the file is, if you can import the module, simply displaying the `repr()` of the module:

```
>>> import urllib
>>> urllib
<module 'urllib' from '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/urllib.pyc'>
>>> import BeautifulSoup
>>> BeautifulSoup
<module 'BeautifulSoup' from '/Library/Python/2.5/site-packages/BeautifulSoup-3.0.6-py2.5.egg/BeautifulSoup.py'>
```

If the import fails, the traceback should show the location of the module also.

One thing to note, if the module installed any command-line tools, you'll have to remove these manually also.. On OS X they are installde in `/usr/local/bin/` - you can find any tool which uses `cx_Oracle` using grep:

```
cd /usr/local/bin/
grep EASY-INSTALL * | grep cx_Oracle
```

Or simply..

```
cd /usr/local/bin/
grep cx_Oracle *
```

Comment: Nice. I never thought of a lot of these methods. Of course, a lot of the problem of removing Python packages can be solved with a proper package manage. I think uninstallation is a big weakness of the easy_install system, as is evidenced by the complications involved with package removal as you have shown.