# pkg_resources.ExtractionError: Can't extract file(s) to egg cache: [Errno 13] Permission denied:

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, easy-install

So, I've been battling this ongoing problem for days and here's my latest dead-end:

I wanted to uninstall cx_Oracle to start fresh. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922323/how-do-i-deactivate-an-egg) that said the way to do that was to delete the egg file.

So I did:

```
rm -rf /Users/xxx/.python-eggs/cx_Oracle-5.1.3-py2.7-macosx-10.8-x86_64.egg-tmp/
```

Which I now see was a total reading comprehension failure on my part, but what's done is done.

Then I tried to run the script and got:

```
 File "time_reporting.py", line 31, in <module>
    import cx_Oracle
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.8-x86_64/egg/cx_Oracle.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.8-x86_64/egg/cx_Oracle.py", line 4, in __bootstrap__
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.8-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 951, in resource_filename
    err.manager        = self
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.8-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 1647, in get_resource_filename
    def get_importer(path_item):
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.8-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 1677, in _extract_resource
    except ImportError:
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.8-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 1017, in get_cache_path
    Resource providers should call this method ONLY after successfully
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.8-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 997, in extraction_error

pkg_resources.ExtractionError: Can't extract file(s) to egg cache

The following error occurred while trying to extract file(s) to the Python egg
cache:

  [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/xxx/.python-eggs/cx_Oracle-5.1.3-py2.7-macosx-10.8-x86_64.egg-tmp'

The Python egg cache directory is currently set to:

  /Users/xxx/.python-eggs

Perhaps your account does not have write access to this directory?  You can
change the cache directory by setting the PYTHON_EGG_CACHE environment
variable to point to an accessible directory.
```

Now I have no idea what to do.  Python 2.7.8, OSX 10.8.5

Comment: _"Perhaps your account does not have write access to this directory?"_ What are the permissions on `/Users/xxx`, `/Users/xxx/.python-eggs` ? Under which identity are you running your commands? Have you tried to set `PYTHON_EGG_CACHE` to `/tmp` for example?

Comment: I'm sorry but I have very little knowledge in this arena and don't really understand your questions and/or how to answer them.  FOr what it's worth, sudo seems to remove this error.

Comment: Please learn how to use virtualenv to manage your Python eggs: http://opensourcehacker.com/2012/09/16/recommended-way-for-sudo-free-installation-of-python-software-with-virtualenv/

Comment: This is all within a virtualenv.  I learned that lesson the hard way a long time ago.

Answer (score 0):

UNIX file permissions and ownerships of the target directories are incorrect. Most likely you have installed stuff as root, making those directories root owned.

[Do not install packages as root in Python](http://opensourcehacker.com/2012/09/16/recommended-way-for-sudo-free-installation-of-python-software-with-virtualenv/), unless you really know what you are doing.

[Use UNIX chmod and chown commands to fix directory permissions](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-use-chmod-and-chown-command/)

... or remove directories with sudo and after this reinstall the packages without sudo:

```
sudo rm -rf /Users/xxx/.python-eggs/
```

Comment: I didn't install or remove the packages with sudo; I meant that when I run my script with sudo, I don't get this error message.

Comment: Whoops, that's a lie.  I did.  But it was within a virtualenv, using easy_install.